# How to not remove head and tail values when using roll apply

Tags: r

I am using roll apply to get a centered moving average on a vector, however, I want to keep the first 12 and last 12 rows.

```
MVA<-Hourly_Frequency_Ratio$Hourly_Frequency
MVA<-rollapply(zoo(MVA), 24, (mean),rule=24)
MVA<-as.data.frame(MVA)
```

How do I keep the rows?

Comment: Use the `fill` argument: `rollapply(zoo(MVA), 24, (mean), rule=24, fill = NA)`

Comment: You can probably just use `MVA <- rollmean(MVA, 24, fill = NA)` . No need to convert to zoo and back, to use rule= or to use rollapply or (mean).